# Airflow fetch data from db and print it out

Tags: airflow

I was tasked with creating a POC where people can fetch data from a db, process it and send it to S3. I'm still learning Airflow and there are things I do not fully understand. I hope you are able to help me out.
So I'm trying to fetch data from mysql db at the moment and print it out. The problem is I always get 'None' returned. I'm trying to utilise xcom but it doesn't work and I read that I shouldn't use xcom for this.
Here's what I have now:

```
def print_query():
query = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='mysql_query')
print(query)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2019, 8, 15),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG('s3_dag_test', default_args=default_args)

python = PythonOperator(
    task_id='print',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_query,
    dag=dag)

query = MySqlOperator(
    task_id='mysql_query',
    sql='SELECT * FROM sakila.actor',
    mysql_conn_id='mysql_db',
    dag=dag)

query >> python
```

First tasks runs fine(mysql_query), however the second one fails as I get None. What is wrong?

Also, the actual error that I get is this:

```
ERROR - print_query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dag'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use context in your python function you must use kwargs and define your callable as

```py
def print_query(**kwargs):
```

Then you can use it as:

```py
def print_query(**kwargs):
    query = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='mysql_query')
    print(query)
```

Or you can add `ti` explictly:

```py
def print_query(ti, **kwargs):
    query = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='mysql_query')
    print(query)
```

Comment: This does get rid of the error however I'm still not able to pass the results from one step to another.

Comment: No, wait - it works now. So I need to pass **kwargs each time. Thank you.